# Event on scrolling up or down

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna detect when the user scrolls. I saw there are some questions about this but those answers didn't help me.
Here is my code:

```
var up = document.getElementById('up');
var down = document.getElementById('down');
function onScroll() {
if (view.scrollTop > 0) {
    console.log("up");
}
if (view.scrollTop < 0) {
    console.log("down");
 }
}
var view = document.getElementById('container');
view.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
```

EDIT: "scroll" instead "wheel" isn't working for me... I must have the "wheel". When I make:

```
if (view.scrolltop <=0) {
    console.log("down");
 }
```

that I get in my console "down" but it appears when I scrolling up too! I have my page in 100% of screen and I have no scrollbars (and I don't want to have).

EDIT2: Here is the code that solved my problem!

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log("scrolling up");
 }
if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log("scrolling down");
 }
});
```

Comment: `view.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);`

Comment: You can use jquery scroll as well https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
window.onscroll
```

to get the scrolling event, then just use

```
.scrollTop
```

to determine your offset from the top of page or an element.

```
window.onscroll = function() { scrollFunction() };

scrollFunction() {

 //code to check if it is scrolling up or down
}
```

Hopefully this was a helpful start.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the jquery method

```
var last = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var Pos = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (Pos > last ){
       // down
   } else {
      // up
   }
   last = Pos;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting @Belmin Bedak's comment.

Use `.scroll` instead of `.wheel`:

```js
var up = document.getElementById('up');
var down = document.getElementById('down');
function onScroll() {
if (view.scrollTop > 0) {
    alert("up");
}
if (view.scrollTop <= 0) {
    alert("down");
 }
}
var view = document.getElementById('container');
view.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>a<br>
b<br>
c<br>
d<br>
e<br>
f<br>
g<br>
h<br>
i<br>
k<br>
l<br>
</div>
```